# How to save List of lastModifiedBy in Spring JPA Auditing

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm implementing Spring JPA Audit in my Spring Boot Application. I have the below Abstract Class which is extended by my entities, where I need to keep track of audits.

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class Auditable<T> {

    @CreatedBy
    @Column(updatable = false)
    protected T createdBy;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(updatable = false)
    protected Date createdDate;

    @LastModifiedBy
    protected T lastModifiedBy;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @UpdateTimestamp
    protected Date lastModifiedDate;
}
```

However the **lastModifiedBy** field stores the "identity" of only the latest user who edited that identity. Is there any way that I can extend it to store a "List" of users who have edited that particular record instead, with the latest editor being appended at the end of that list? I'm using Postgres as my database, by the way.

All the documentation available has no such implementation. I was thinking of building my own custom audit setup. Thought of asking for views here.

Answer (score -1):

Storing a **list** of users who have edited a particular **record** with the latest editor being appended at the end of that list can be achieved with a custom **audit** setup. Spring Data JPA's built-in auditing mechanisms are designed to capture a single user responsible for the last modification and creation of an entity, which might not fit your requirement directly. Here's a high-level approach to implement this custom auditing in your Spring Boot application using Postgres as the database:

Create a new **entity** to represent audit history:

```
@Entity
public class AuditHistory {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private YourEntity auditedEntity;

    @CreatedBy
    private T editor;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date editTimestamp;
}
```

Modify your **Auditable** class to handle the list of audit history:

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class Auditable<T> {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "auditedEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<AuditHistory> auditHistory = new ArrayList<>();

    // Other audit fields like createdBy, createdDate, lastModifiedBy, lastModifiedDate

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void updateAuditHistory() {
        // Create a new audit history entry
        AuditHistory auditEntry = new AuditHistory();
        auditEntry.setEditor(lastModifiedBy); // Set the current editor
        auditEntry.setEditTimestamp(new Date()); // Set the current timestamp
        auditEntry.setAuditedEntity(this); // Set the audited entity

        // Add the new entry to the list
        auditHistory.add(auditEntry);
    }
}
```

Whenever an entity is created or updated, the **updateAuditHistory** method will automatically add an entry to the auditHistory list, capturing the editor and timestamp.

When you query your entity, you can access the **auditHistory** list to get the complete history of edits for that entity.

```
YourEntity entity = yourEntityRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
List<AuditHistory> auditHistory = entity.getAuditHistory();
```

You can then iterate through **auditHistory** to get the list of users who edited the entity over time.

I hope this approach helps you solve the issue.